# Both coefficient and standard error are zero in table of latex

Tags: r, latex, logistic-regression, coefficients, standard-error

My dependent variable is binary.
Independent variable is GDP per capita. 
There are several five more variables and two of them are interaction term.
I use logit model by glm function in r.

Problem is, stargazer comment in r shows a significant coefficient and SE for GDP variable. But, table in latex shows 0.00000*** for coefficient and 0.00000 for SE as well.

What's wrong with it? 
There is no problem with multicollineaty. I checked it with VIF already.

[image]

Comment: you could try rescaling  that predictor so that the coefficient is more reasonable

Comment: This question might be better suited to Cross Validation.

Comment: @user20650 Thank you! rescaling you said is a kind of log or log10.... Is that right? Cause I got reasonable coefficient value for GDP when I put log for gdp. Of course, coefficients of other variables are still same!

Comment: Well it depends, sometimes a log scale transform might work. But for a gdp variable it may be enough to divide it by, for example, 1e4, so that instead of the gdp coefficient giving the change per one unit gdp, it is the change per 10k unit gdp. (imo more interpretable, as its not really sensible to think of changes in £1).

Comment: Here is a wee example: Create a new variable to show using it will create small coefficients: default regression with unscaled variable `mtcars$wt2 <- mtcars$wt* 1e4 ; m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt2, mtcars) ; summary(m1)`. To get more reasonable (and imo more interpretable) coefficients, scale the predictor: `m2 <- lm(mpg ~ I(wt2/1e4), mtcars) ; 
summary(m2)` (note the 1e4 to scale with is arbitrary - chose a value that will make the coefficients reasonable but are also on a scale that interpretation is sensible).